# .net core project.json intellisense not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, package.json

Just installed VS2015 and .net core on my machine, but for some reason i get no intellisense in project.json. On my other machine it works fine. Any idea what went wrong here?

[image]

[image]

**All extensions installed:**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586

Installed Version: Professional

LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015  
Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015

Visual Basic 2015 
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015 
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Add New File   3.5
The fastest and easiest way to add new files to any project - including files that start with a dot

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1   14.1.20907.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v2.8.1   14.0.11123.0
Azure App Service Tools v2.8.1

Bundler & Minifier   2.1.279
Adds support for bundling and minifying JavaScript, CSS and HTML files in any project.

Common Azure Tools   1.8
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

File Icons   1.6
Adds icons for files that are not recognized by Solution Explorer

File Nesting   2.5.63
Automatically nest files based on file name and enables developers to nest and unnest any file manually

Image Optimizer   3.6.94
Uses industry standard tools to optimize any JPEG, PNG and Gifs - including animated Gifs. Can do both lossy and lossless optimization.

Image Sprites   1.4.45
Boost your website's performance by creating image sprites to reduce the amount of HTTP requests needed.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service

JavaScript Project System   2.0
JavaScript Project System

Markdown Editor   1.8.166
A full featured Markdown editor with live preview and syntax highligting. Supports GitHub flavored Markdown.

Microsoft .NET Core Tools (Preview 2)   14.1.20907.0
Microsoft .NET Core Tools (Preview 2)

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NuGet Package Manager   3.5.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

Open Command Line   2.1.176
Opens a command line at the root of the project. Support for all consoles such as CMD, PowerShell, Bash etc. Provides syntax highlighting, Intellisense and execution of .cmd and .bat files.

Package Installer   1.8.87
Makes it easier, faster and more convenient than ever to install Bower, npm, JSPM, TSD, Typings and NuGet packages to any project

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

Python Tools for Visual Studio   2.2.40623.00
Python Tools for Visual Studio provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, Interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

Python Tools for Visual Studio - Django Integration   2.2.40623.00
Provides templates and integration for the Django web framework.

Python Tools for Visual Studio - Profiling Support   2.2.40623.00
Profiling support for Python projects.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60519.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript   1.8.36.0
TypeScript tools for Visual Studio

Web Accessibility Checker   1.3.33
The easiest way to perform accessibility checks on any ASP.NET web application. Fully customizable and support all the major international accessibility standards.

Web Compiler   1.11.319
Compiler for LESS, Sass and CoffeeScript files

Web Essentials 2015.3   3.0.235
Adds many useful features to Visual Studio for web developers. Requires Visual Studio 2015
```

**Update**: Apparenlty the intellisense works if I create the project on drive C. However when project is created on different logical disk, its not working.

Comment: I'm sure you checked already, but does it pop up when you press `ctrl+space` (instead of on `.`)?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I checked that. Nothing. Plus it should show automatically anyways.

Comment: OK. Just checking the obvious, since I know there's a VS option to not show intellisense on `.`. Is there any more details you can provide? Shooting in the dark still, but what about the machine you're on and which service pack it has, .NET versions installed, where you got your copy of VS2015, if you had any other versions of VS before installing this one, etc. And did you use the same installer on both machines?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the intellisense is driven by the NuGet cache, not by web requests. (I may be completely wrong on this).

You can confirm by pulling the package down in another project.

Comment: Can you post what extensions you have installed? `Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio > Copy Info`.

Comment: Just updated with the info.

Comment: Ok, the intellisense is not working. But can you restore the packages and run your project without further problems?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.  My projects like yours are not on drive C also. It looks like my problem was with ReSharper.  I don't know if you are using ReSharper but here how I fixed my problem.

When I changed ReSharper IntelliSense from Visual Studio to ReSharper, I got my IntelliSense back.

[image]

Comment: No, I'm not currently using ReSharper.

Comment: Actually for me it was switching from ReSharper to Visual studio for JSON files only. (Version 2016.1.2) No need to disable ReSharper IntelliSense for everything.

Comment: yep, for me the problem also was in ReSharper